# Sharing an XML file between two projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010

I have looked around and simply cannot find a way to open a linked XML file. My folder structure is like this:

```
...\projects\ConfigService\
...\projects\Shared\
...\projects\WebTool\
```

Inside the Shared folder I have a single XML file that will be modified by the WebTool project and read by the ConfigService (many times after each one is built and running). To make things as simple as possible, I simply tried "add as link" at the XML in each project, but then how do I actually get a full path to the linked object so I can open it? I use a link because the file will be changed after my projects are built, but I will not rebuild.

All answers I have found either try to pack the linked file into the project's binary, or the instructions are for adding classes/code instead of just a flat resource.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Where would the file be at runtime?  Presumably you need the full path at runtime of the ConfigService right?

Comment: The file would not be moved, it would stay in the Shared folder so that while running, the WebTool can update it and the ConfigService can see the changes the next time it opens the file.

Comment: Ok, so how will this be deployed?  You're talking about how the development project is configured, but presumably you will deploy this somewhere and it will not always be running inside of visual studio.

Comment: The projects are just ASPX webpages with code behind, so they just sit in those folders on the server. So for every server I deploy to, I need a relative path to the shared XML, otherwise I'd just use an absolute path.

Comment: Do the classes in question have access to the `HttpContext` or `HttpServerUtility`, if so then the simplest solution is to use `HttpServerUtility.MapPath()`.

Comment: Aha, this is getting closer. I used this: `string fullFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"..\Shared\SharedServiceNames.xml");` but it threw an exception that I can't use '..\' to escape the top directory.

Comment: you want: `string fullFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\projects\Shared\SharedServiceNames.xml");`  The `~` character tells the web server "substitute the root virtual directory path here".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15679/discussion-between-sho-minamimoto-and-coding-gorilla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked out best for him was to use the `Server.MapPath()` method to find his `Shared` folder regardless of where in the file system his website was rooted.  Since it will always be `[virtual-directory]\Shared` this works out perfectly and he doesn't need to worry about config settings.

Comment: Yep, this is a great answer! My line to get a full path is: `string fullFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\Shared\SharedFile.xml");`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use an `app.config` file to resolve this.  Here's how you would do it.

In the WebTool service, and in the Config service, add an `app.config` file with the following text:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="XmlFileLocation" value="c:\folder\projects\shared\myfile.xml" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then, you can retrieve the file location in each program by using the following:

```
string filepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlFileLocation"];
```

You'll have to add a reference to System.Configuration in your projects though.

Good luck!

Comment: This is a great solution for one server, but if I deploy to multiple servers, my `\projects\` folder will be in a different location for each. Is there a way to make this more scalable?

Comment: I do lots of deploys across servers and I find that this configuration file system solves tons of those problems :) For example, let's say I have ten copies of ConfigService running on virtual machines, and one copy of WebTool running on the local PC.  The ConfigService machines would have `\\WebToolServer\share\folder\projects\myfile.xml` and the WebTool PC would have `c:\share\folder\projects\myfile.xml` - provided you shared `c:\share` with windows file services :)

Comment: Aha, I see. This answer is great for having a single XML file that a bunch of servers interact with (which is fantastically scalable :D). However for my projects, I have a single shared XML for every server, no two servers should talk to each other. In which case I think Gorilla's answer is an easier fix, but this works perfectly fine as well. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Sure - if you want, they can always point to a single shared folder for each server.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go
One depends on how you are going to deploy. If they are all going to same folder, the Mr Oded's solution is a quick and simple.
If you are deploying to a more complex folder structure e.g

```
MyApps
  Shared
  ConfigService
  WebTool
```

The create a folder structure that mirrors that and set the output directory in each project to the relevant one (instead of the default bin\debug bin\release). The you can grab it with a relative path from from each tool e.g. (..\MyXmlFile.xml).

That said, I like neither of the above.

What else in shared? If there's a dll, then may be it should have a method that returns the location of the file, or the content, and let it manage where that location is.

PS don't forget seeing as it is exposed on the file system (somewhere), you need to cope with some well meaning individual deleting or modifying it.

Comment: This is an internal-facing tool for my department only, so security is not really an issue (at least right now). And these are ASPX pages that will sit in that exact folder structure on the server.